# Etymology on "egging on"

Tags: etymology

What is the etymology on "egging on"?

> e.g. It was Jack who did it. But Jane was really **egging him on**.

Does it actually relate to eggs, or is it simply derived from "urging on"?

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=egg

Comment: @JeffSahol Yes, I looked at that. It suggests the term has something to do with "edge", but I still don't see how it arose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The etymology of the verb *egg (on)* is the same as that of *edge*. It is of Old Norse origin, and once described in particular the sharp edge of a sword. Perhaps those who were egged on were once so encouraged by the threat of laceration.

Comment: Or made to listen to U2 guitar riffs incessantly.

Comment: This sense of 'edge'-ing on seems diametrically opposite to 'urge'-ing on as more commonly understood.

Comment: The NOAD lists as the etymology for *egg(2)*, "ORIGIN Middle English : from Old Norse **eggja 'incite.'** " It also lists *eggja* as a related etymological word in the entry for *edge*. I'm not sure how those two are related, but your guess sounds good in the absence of others.

Comment: The words in the etymology appear to have meant more along the lines of *point* than *edge*; perhaps they carried the idea of poking rather than laceration, and it is from this idea that we get *egg*.

Comment: To *egg on* is proper old. Here's an example from [1594](http://books.google.fi/books?id=kOQbU56suzcC&pg=PA225&dq=%22egging+on%22+OR+%22egged+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=cqyiT4OxB6WB4gTd0KTrCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22egged%20on%22&f=true): *... should remayne whith more security then they can wel hope to do vnder any Inglish competitor, if he come to the crowne, who shalbe continually **egged on** by his owne kynred...*

Answer (score 5):

Robert Hendrickson, *Facts on File Encyclopedia of Word and Phrase Origins*, fourth edition (2008) has this entry for *egg on*:

> **egg on** The expression *to egg on* has nothing to do with hen's eggs or any other kind of eggs. Neither does it derive from Norman invaders pricking Anglo-Saxon prisoners in the buttocks with their *ecgs* ("the points of their spears") when urging them to move faster, as one old story claims. *To egg on* is jut a form of the obsolete English verb "to edge": to incite, provoke, encourage, urge on, push someone nearer to the edge. To *egg* someone meant the same as to *edge* someone and was used that way until about 1566, when the expression was first lengthened and became *to egg on*.

John Ayto, *Dictionary of Word Origins* (1990) has this comment within a longer entry for *egg*:

> *Egg* 'incite' as in 'egg on', is a Scandinavian borrowing too. It comes from Old Norse *eggja*, which was a relative or derivative of egg 'edge' (a cousin of English *edge*).

And Eric Partridge, *Origins: A Short Etymological Dictionary of Modern English* (1958) has this:

> **egg** (2) to to urge or incite; ME *eggen*: ON *eggja*, (lit) to put an egg, or edge, on: [cross reference omitted].

So even though an egg doesn't have any identifiable edges, the *egg* of *egg on* is all about provoking someone (or some group of people) to the edge of action.

Comment: [c. 1200, from Old Norse eggja "to goad on, incite," from egg "edge"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/egg) so yep.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of the word "egg" as in the expression "egging someone on" actually is expropriated from the first syllable of the customary pronunciation of "exhortation." To exhort is to incite, urge, encourage, push, challenge, advocate and counsel one on to their highest or most extreme attainments.

Comment: Do you have any official source you can cite for that statement?

Answer (score -1):

The collection of root distinctions mentioned here are aligned with edge/edging - as in 'to push', 'provoke' and 'insist'. To 'egg on' though invokes the opposite; to 'pull', 'lead' and 'incite'.  They have similar roots, but different positions. That connects it back to being related to 'egg' and not 'edge'. It would link 'egg on' to the incubation of a chick to hatch. So, to 'egg on' would be - to engage in actions that nurture & promote an idea to fruition - to bust an action from it's shell, to 'hatch' it.

Comment: Is this just your opinion or do you have any evidence?

Comment: What type of evidence would you like? I was very curious about this phrase to understand the distinction better.  I liked what I found here, which are the historical Etymological forms.  The  idea that 'edge' and 'egg' are similar doesn’t work. When deconstructing the phrase with both 'edge' and 'egg', only egg works with 'on'.  It is a methodology of engaging in linguistic usage semantics rather than looking for what fits historically. I read all the comments. That 'egg', in it's pure connotation, was dismissed as a misinterpretation in these answers, doesn't connect with how it is used.

Comment: Well, you have to look at how the word was actually used throughout history. In this case, "egg" meaning "urge" dates back to ~1200, but the expression "egg on" was not used until ~1566. Furthermore, the spelling of "edge" and "egg" was exactly the same during Middle English. A good free resource to start in this case would be [MED](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED13069).

Comment: The question was about the etymology. The answers here already have attempted to give it credibility as an etymological question. It is not. The phrases, 'egg on' and 'egging on' are aligned with colloquialisms rather than the strict grammatical historical interpretations. My response is to, again, deconstruct the phrase to get to an accurate answer.  The questioner though, was looking for an answer in the wrong place. Etymological roots are all well and good to look at, however, 'egg on' and 'egging on' are from the fruits of connective usages, developed well after the original roots.

Comment: egg 2  (ĕg)
tr.v. egged, egg·ing, eggs
To encourage or incite to action. Used with on: The racing fans egged their favorites on. To 'edge on' is to make slow movements or have a limited advancement. Not the same usage.